# Can't create a Module with __init__.py

Tags: python, python-module, sys

I have 2 situations to import some files into the main script.
One works and the other doesn't and I can't tell the difference.

**Scenario that works**

```
main.py    
models  
├── __init__.py   
├── vggs.py  
├── resnets.py
```

where `__init__.py`

```
from .vggs import *
from .resnets import *
```

and `main.py`

```
from models import *   # works fine
```

**Scenario that doesn't work**

```
scripts
├── main.py    
models  
├── __init__.py   
├── vggs.py  
├── resnets.py
```

This time, I append the models folder to the `sys.path` in the `main.py`:

```
sys.path.append('../models')

# These don't work --> ModuleNotFoundError: No module name models
import models   
from models import * 

# However, these work
from vggs import *
from resnets import *
```

Why can I import each of the files but I cannot import the entire models folders as a module even I have the `__init__.py`?

Comment: `from vggs import *` would only work if you are using Python 2. Is that the case? You need to add the **parent** directory of `models` to your path. The path is the list of directories in which Python looks for a `models.py` file or `models` directory.

Comment: Note that you really, really want to move to Python 3, *as soon as possible*. Python 2 is [reaching end of life in 8 months time](https://pythonclock.org/) and anyone starting new projects or trying to learn the language today would be wasting their time using Python 2.

Comment: I am using Python 3 :) Thank you!

Comment: Right, in which case your original `from vggs import *` and `from resnets import *` statements inside `from models import *` can't work *either*, as those are always resolved as top-level names in Python 3. Only `from .vggs import *` or `from models.vggs import *` and `from .resnets import *` or `from models.resnets import *` would import from the nested modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the `models` directory itself to the `sys.path` list. Now Python looks for modules **inside** of that directory. There is no `../models/models/__init__.py` nor is there a `../models/models.py`, so `import models` fails.

Add the *parent* directory to `sys.path()`:

```
sys.path.append('..')
```

Python then finds `../models/__init__.py` and so `import models` then succeeds.

A much more robust version first determines the absolute path of the `script/` directory then adds the parent path to `sys`:

```
import os.path

scripts_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(scripts_dir))
```

Otherwise, `..` is relative to the current working directory, and that's not necessarily the `scripts/` directory.